# NetLogo: Setting a turtle's variable based on its neighbours on a network

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'm creating a virtual society where turtles have a 3 dimensional vector of opinions.What I'd like is that each turtle in the network has a vector of opinions that is related to turtles in the network following a normal distribution.

A possibility I reckon would be to create turtles with random opinions and then at the end of the setup process bring these opinions close together . So for instance, turtle 0 has opinions `[0.2   0.8   0.6]`, turtle 1 has `[0.7   0.5   0.5]` and turtle 2 has `[0.9   0.4   0.1]`. The mean being `[0.6   0.6   0.1]`, then each turtle's vector of opinions would be reestablished following a normal distribution `[0.6±0.1   0.6±0.1   0.6±0.1]`

Below what I am trying, which doesn't work because my `(map mean ([opinions] of my-nearby-turtles)`bit gives the mean of all dimensions of opinions for each turtle instead of the mean of each dimension of opinions for all turtles...

```
ask turtles [
        set opinions n-values 3 [random-float 1]
        (foreach opinions (map mean ([opinions] of turtles)) [ [a b] -> set a random-normal b 0.1])
      ]
end
```

Comment: Can you please provide some example data? Pretend that the turtle has 3 neighbours and create some vectors with fake values, what do you want the turtle to actually generate from the neighbours' vectors?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @JenB. I have modified my question to try and be clearer, let me know if you need more details to help me figure this out!

Comment: @JenB I used some of what you taught me elsewhere to cobble up an answer, I think it works but I'll keep testing... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have tackled it, I await comments from more senior NetLoggers...

```
ask turtles [
   set opinions n-values 3 [random-float 1]
  (foreach opinions [x ->
    let avg-network map mean ([opinions] of turtles)
    let pp position x opinions
    set opinions replace-item pp opinions random-normal (item pp avg-network) 0.1])
  ]
end
```